# Adding a list of constants to all rows in different columns

Tags: r

This should be a very simple task, but I'm having difficulty working it out. Say I have a dataframe with 5 columns of numbers, and I want to add c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to each row depending on which column it is in. So I add 1 to all values the first column, 2 to all values in the second column, etc...

What's the simplest way to do this without using for loops? My current solution is to repeat my vector c(1,2,3,4,5) by the number of rows of my dataframe, and then add this to my dataframe. But is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2):

We could replicate the values by 'col' and add, so that each element is replicated to get the lengths same while we do the addition

```
df1 + (1:5)[col(df1)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 2:4, col3 = 1:3, col4 = 2:4, col5 = 1:3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it is not working as intended. This adds 1 to the first row of the first column, 2 to the second row of the first column etc... I want to add 1 to all rows of the first column, 2 to all rows of the second column, etc...

Comment: @Jackdaw sorry, there was a confusion because the dimensions are the same.  Please check the updte

Comment: Perfect solution. Simple but effective!

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `t`

```
data.frame(t(t(df) + (1:5)))
```